# How does KMeans algorithm plot points?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

How does the KMeans algorithm handle the plotting of a data point for clustering purposes?

For example, consider 3 data points that have many features. Out of that, one feature has the foll: values:

Length_of_Room:

- 2.05
- 2.35
- 5.75

Will the first 2 entries be placed in the same cluster because the values are closer to each other (Assuming that all other features are also similar)?

Please help me out!

Comment: What do you mean by "plotting"? K-means does not plot. It also can only handle data that is in R^d. So a feature may only have one value. It's your job to transform the data appropriately to get vectors in R^d.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse What I meant by plotting is that, one row in a dataset will be considered as a point in the plane right. Similarly KMeans takes all points in the dataset and clusters them accordingly.  

Similarly for 3 separate rows or  'points', if one feature called 'Length_of_Room' has the above mentioned values, will the first 2 points be close to each other because the values are closer.

Comment: first the Kmeans do not "plot in a plan" as @Anony-Mousse said. re-read the comment. Second, this will depend on the distance you defined. Id it's euclidian then the answer is (probably) yes, but for some, it's rather more complex...

Comment: @Alexis Just to clarify. So if I'm using Euclidian distance, points containing [2.05, 2.35] will belong to the same cluster and the point containing [5.75] will belong to a different cluster right?

Comment: that depends on the other points and of the number of clusters. It is not because two points are close that they will belong to the same cluster. for some points, the closest point will be in a different cluster. you may want to play with the two moons data set in sklearn to see this...

Comment: @Alexis k-means cannot use arbitrary distances, so you don't have this choice. It's squared Euclidean, or the mean does not optimize the distances.

Comment: Rahul: it depends on your data. K-means minimizes the variance of clusters, so close values are typically in the same cluster, far values in different clusters.

Answer (score 0):

The concept is correct i.e., features with similar values will be clustered together based on their euclidean distance.

To learn more read this: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#k-means.

FYI: the objective function to minimize is:

[image]